# Android Studio 0.5.3 cannot resolve Android classes

Tags: android-studio

I've recently updated to Android Studio 0.5.3 and then to 0.5.4. From version 0.5.3 it cannot resolve Android classes. Compile is OK but IDE autocomplete is broken and big part of sources is now marked as error. Looks like this:
[image: Cannot resolve symbols]

Root `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:0.9.+'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

Project's `build.gradle`:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.crashlytics.tools.gradle:crashlytics-gradle:1.+'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'android'
apply plugin: 'crashlytics'
repositories {
    maven { url 'http://download.crashlytics.com/maven' }
}


android {
    compileSdkVersion 14
    buildToolsVersion '19.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 14
        targetSdkVersion 14
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            runProguard false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:okhttp:1.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.2.+'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:+'
    compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.2.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.0.30'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}
```

I don't think it is a gradle issue, as build completes successfully. What can be incorrect? Or how can I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fixed the issue by specifying following line in project's iml:

```
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Android API 14 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
```

instead of:

```
<orderEntry type="jdk" jdkName="Maven Android 4.0 Platform" jdkType="Android SDK" />
```

Sometimes it reverts back. It's a bit annoying but better than having red sources and no code assist.